# The LPCSTR type string is garbled or displayed error

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, converters, lpcstr

I have a `LPCSTR` that I want to convert to `std::string` or `char*`.

```
LPCSTR strName;
_tprintf(_T("%s\n"), strName);
```

I'm trying to get all the audio equipment on the computer and displayed, but to get the `LPCSTR` type of direct output is garbled, use the above code to output the correct results.

Is there a way to save the correct output?

The following is the complete code:

```
Add a dependency to the property:
comctl32.lib;winmm.lib;dsound.lib;dxguid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib
```

#### ListSoundDev.h

```
#ifndef _LISTSOUNDDEV_HEAD_
#define _LISTSOUNDDEV_HEAD_
#include<tchar.h>
#include <dshow.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<mmsystem.h>
#include<mmreg.h>
#include<dsound.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Quartz.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dsound.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxguid.lib")

#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids")
using namespace std;

typedef struct _DevItem
{
    LPCSTR strName;
    GUID guid;
} DevItem;
#endif
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include"ListSoundDev_head.h"
std::vector<DevItem>    m_CapDevices;
BOOL CALLBACK DSEnumCallback(LPGUID lpGuid, LPCSTR lpcstrDescription, LPCSTR lpcstrModule, LPVOID lpContext)
{
    std::vector<DevItem> *pLst = (std::vector<DevItem> *) lpContext;
    if (pLst)
    {
        DevItem item;
        memset(&item, 0, sizeof(item));
        item.strName = lpcstrDescription;
        if (lpGuid)
            item.guid = *lpGuid;
        else
            item.guid = GUID_NULL;
        pLst->push_back(item);
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<DevItem>::iterator it;
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "chs");
    hr = DirectSoundCaptureEnumerate((LPDSENUMCALLBACKW)DSEnumCallback, (LPVOID)&m_CapDevices);
    for (it = m_CapDevices.begin(); it != m_CapDevices.end(); it++){
        _tprintf(_T("%s\n"), it->strName);//output correct
        printf("%s\n",it->strName);//output error
        std::cout << it->strName << std::endl;//output error
    }
}
```

### Expected output:

> 麦克风 (Realtek High Definition Au

### Actual output:

> KQ螛

### Expected  output:

> Realtek Digital Input (Realtek

### Actual output:

> R

How can I that  `printf()` or `std::cout` can directly output the correct results?

Comment: The macro (or type-alias) `LPCSTR` is an acronym for "Long Pointer to Constant STRing", i.e. it is a `const char*`. You should not "convert" it to a `char*`, other than by *copying* it. On the other hand, there is a constructor (and assignment operator) that allows you to create a `std::string` from a `const char*`, so that "conversion" is simple. As for converting to a wide character string, search for "converting multibyte character string to wide character string".

Comment: Thanks for adding code, but that's not a **minimal** example.  You should be able to reduce it to 5-10 lines by creating a LPCSTR object directly, rather than with all those API calls.  Read how to create a [mcve] and then [edit] your question appropriately.

Comment: The fact that `_tprintf` shows the string correctly but `printf` does not indicates that a) you are building a Unicode build, and b) you actually have a Unicode string, not an ANSI string as you assume. `DevItem::strName` should be declared to have `LPCWSTR` (or `LPTSTR` if you want to be able to build either ANSI or Unicode build). [The documentation for `DSEnumCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.dsenumcallback.aspx) appears to be incorrect; in fact, there's comment to that effect at the bottom of the page. It's actually given Unicode strings.

Comment: @TobySpeight It appears that the crux of the problem does in fact lie in those API calls. Through a series of unfortunate events (involving an apparent documentation bug), a Unicode string ends up being effectively cast to `LPCSTR`.

Comment: Note also that, and I quote, "The memory pointed to by `lpGuid`, `lpcstrDescription`, and `lpcstrModule` is local in scope. If you want to save these values, you must allocate them in global memory." In other words, the memory pointed to by `lpcstrDescription` may become invalid as soon as the function returns. You currently save that pointer; you should instead copy and save the character data it points to. I'd make `DevItem::strName` a `std::wstring`.

Comment: @Igor, in which case, creating a minimal example would have enabled the creation of a targeted question asking why the result of that function didn't behave as expected.  Please encourage posters to conduct this kind of preliminary investigation before posting a very general question that most of us can't help with (it wasn't even tagged as being a Windows question...)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer, I have solved this problem.

The solution is to use the following code to convert.

**The character set is Unicode.**

```
char newStr[100];
wcstombs(newStr, (wchar_t*)it->strName, 100);
printf("newStr=%s\n", newStr);
```

**The character set is Multibyte**

```
printf("%s\n", it->strName);
```

However, when I write this program in the C + + console to obtain the name of the audio device for the microphone (Realtek High Definition Au, but in MFC using this code to get the device name for the microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio) What is the reason?

Comment: The comment at the bottom of [this documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.directsoundcaptureenumerate.aspx) suggests calling `CoInitialize` first might help with the truncated device names.

Comment: If you want the same code to work in both Unicode and ANSI build, then a) make `strName` have `LPCTSTR` type (note the T); b) cast `lpcstrDescription` to `LPCTSTR` when assigning to `strName`, and c) print it with `_tprintf`